# Prevent text from wrapping when flex item has scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, flexbox

I want to display content with a maximum height, but a variable width.

If the content is too tall, then I want a specific child element to scroll, rather than the entire content.

If I set `overflow-y: auto` on said child element, then if a scrollbar appears, the contents of the child element wrap when they wouldn't need to if they used more width (the width of a scrollbar).

If I set `overflow-y: scroll`, then wrapping is avoided, but a scrollbar is shown even if not necessary.

Any ideas of how to avoid the unnecessary wrapping without always showing a scrollbar?

```css
.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.flex-container table {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <p>Top</p>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>One two three four five</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>One two three four five</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>One two three four five</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>One two three four five</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>Bottom</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0dnze1e7/

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your HTML by replacing the `<p>` with `<div>` and modified the CSS. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/0dnze1e7/3/)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.flex-container .dynamic {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="outer">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>Top</div>
    <div class="dynamic">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>One two three four five</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>One two three four five</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>One two three four five</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>One two three four five</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>One two three four five</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>One two three four five</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>Bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I view the fiddle in Firefox, it looks like the content now takes up the full available width, whereas the original (intentionally) only takes up as much width as is required for the content.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a minimum width like below. Not necessarily 178px. This value is only for the example you have given above.

```
.flex-container table {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 178px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my actual use case, I've already set a minimum width, but that doesn't help for cases where the table will end up being wider than the minimum width. Increasing the minimum width to cover all possibilities means that the table would end up being too wide in most cases.